# can I securely access Gmail for a Rails app on shared hosting non-SSL without putting credentials at risk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, oauth, openid

That is, want a Rails application that lets me see a customized view of the user's Gmail calendar.  But it'll be on shared hosting so don't want to store credentials, or have them in the clear.

Question: Can I securely access Gmail for a Rails app on shared hosting non-SSL without putting credentials at risk?  How would I do this?  (e.g. does OAuth or OpenID solve this)

Requirements would be:

- Rails application will call Google Calendar via API
- No credentials stored on shared hosting site (e.g. in database or whatever) - MANDATORY
- Rails site is non-SSL - MANDATORY (for the purpose of this question)
- Ability to stay logged in whilst browser still open - DESIREABLE  (assume using session id...assuming this is secure)

For example exiting approach I've used which wouldn't satisfy my requirements on my non-SSL rails site (on a shared host) would be:

```
# Get Google Calendar
service = GCal4Ruby::Service.new
service.authenticate("<google account name>", "<password>")  # <== requires password
cal = GCal4Ruby::Calendar.find(service, "myCalendar")[0]

# Get Google Events
search_str = "<search str>"
@events = GCal4Ruby::Event.find(cal, search_str, params)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get mixed content if you try to include in an `http` page an `https` Google calendar view loaded as an `iframe`.

If you're just doing API calls, as long as the API calls are from your server to an encrypted endpoint, `https://calendar.google.com` or something similar, then there are no problems.

If you're doing API calls from a non-`http` page in the browser, then a determined attacker will be able to eavesdrop on any data you serve, including credentials sent to the browser for forwarding to the calendar service.

If you're sending credentials to the browser you should also worry about exfiltration via XSS.

Comment: but wouldn't this require SSL for my rails site?  and yes it was API calls I was proposing

Comment: @Greg, if you're doing the API calls from your server, and never send the credentials to the client, then eavesdropping is only a concern for the connection between your server and the API is a problem.  Make sure you connect to an `https` version of the API and you should be secure against eavesdropping.

Comment: thanks, but you're assuming then I use something like OAuth or OpenID or something for the user to authenticate to Google Calendar?  i.e. I'm not clear of how the user authenticates to Google Calendar prior to my app then being able to request the calendar for the user, massage it, and present it back to the user

Comment: @Greg, what is your question?  Do you want to know how to authenticate to Google Calendar?

Comment: was assuming that without some other approach (which is what I'm asking about) that my rails code would need to get the "password" from the user.  e.g. service = GCal4Ruby::Service.new,     service.authenticate("<google account name>", ",<password>").  But in this case this breaks what I'm trying to do, i.e. avoid having the password passed to my non-SSL rails app.

Comment: @Greg, see http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#auth : "If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an individual's private data), then the application must provide an OAuth 2.0 token with the request. The application may also provide the API key, but it doesn't have to. ... Google displays an OAuth dialog to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token."